# How do I make req.body.password not equal to undefined?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

In my html I have,

`<input name="password" type="password" required class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">`

and in my node I have,

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })


app.get('/login.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('./login.html', {root: __dirname});
})

app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, (req,res)=>{
    req.body.password
})
```

but, the req.body.password is undefined or empty. How do I make it actually grab what the user is inputting? It does not work for any of them but, I just used password as an example. All the packages were downloaded correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const jsonParser = express.json();

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

// CHANGE THIS TO DATABASE LATER OF USERS
const users = [];

//listen for requests

app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/index.html", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./index.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.get("/login.html", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./login.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.post("/login", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello");
  console.log(req.body.password);
  res.json(req.body.password);
});

app.get("/signup.html", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./signup.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.post("/signup", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {});

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./404.html", { root: __dirname });
});
```

And when I send a POST request to the `/login` path using the following payload:

```json
{
    "password": "Check for Stack Overflow"
}
```

I get this on the console:

```
$ node app
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/root/404.html'
Hello
Check for Stack Overflow
```

I use the following end point: http://2886795314-3000-ollie08.environments.katacoda.com/

And I used POSTMan and got this right now:

[image: preview]

---

*Previous Answer...*

You have to use `res` object to send something. For example, to send a JSON structure, you can do:

```
res.json(req.body.password)
```

So your code will be:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.get("/login.html", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./login.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.post("/login", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body.password);
});
```

Also I could see that you are not using a `.listen` or export of your modules. You may as well need to listen it to a port to run! So use:

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started in port 3000!");
});
```

At the end. So your complete file looks like:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.get("/login.html", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./login.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.post("/login", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body.password);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started in port 3000!");
});
```

Also, please consider reading [Express "Hello World" example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). It has the best example in the easiest way possible from the original documentation.

Comment: I meant to say req.body.password is equal to undefined.

Comment: @gego144 Can you try this? `const urlencodedParser = express.json();`?

Comment: It still equal to undefined.

Comment: @gego144 Have you got the complete code in some place like https://CodeSandbox.io or GitHub?

Comment: I've uploaded it to github. https://github.com/gego144/to-do-list-website

Comment: @gego144 Check out the answer. Updated with the right contents. It works for me.

Comment: @gego144 See this: https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-06650cceb509.gif or https://i.imgur.com/zxqqd6r.mp4

Answer (score 0):

`req.body.password` is kind of like a variable. It 'returns' it's value, but you're not doing anything with what it returns.

It's not clear what you mean with return. If you want to log something to a console, you can do that:

```
console.log(req.body.password);
```

Comment: The problem is the user is trying to use it on browser.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I can't tell from context what they meant. It would be pretty weird to return the password back to the browser, so I think it's a valid guess =)

Comment: Agreed with you... Haha. True that.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post, I meant to say that req.body.password is empty.

Comment: @gego144 how do you know? Your sample code is (at least) weird

Comment: When I try to console.log(req.body.password), I get the error, Cannot read property 'password' of undefined.

Comment: How do I make it log its value instead of undefined?